# Javascript Time Comparisons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two issues I need to solve using javascript or jQuery.

1) I need to test whether the current time falls between 7am and 7pm.

```
var now = new Date();
if (now >= *7am* && now < *7pm*){} else {}
```

2) On document load, I need a function to run everyday at 7am and 7pm.

Any help is appreciated.

---

Resolved part 2 by running a time check every 15 minutes.

```
var checkTime = setInterval(myFunction(), 900000);
```

Comment: are you looking for local time or a specific time zone?

Comment: Here's a suggestion. At Stack Overflow, we like separate questions instead of part 1 and part 2. That way, it's more useful to other people. The second part of the question is really interesting. There's surely a better answer than checking every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `var currentHour = (new Date()).getHours();` to retrieve the specific hour as an integer between 0 and 23, according to the local timezone of your environment:

```
var currentHour = (new Date()).getHours();
if (currentHour >= 7 && currentHour < 19) { /* stuff */ } else { /* other stuff }
```

If you need to get UTC, there is the `.getUTCHours()` method.

The documentation has more information if you're interested: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours

Comment: No, why would it? 0 == midnight, 1 == 1am, ... 7 = 7am.

Comment: Oops, sorry, deleted my comment, but yeah, I didn't realize hours do start at 0, not 1

Comment: Any thoughts on how I could have a function run automatically every 7am and 7pm?

Comment: Nevermind... decided to simply run a time check every 15 mins via setInterval.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Date.getHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours)

```
$(function(){
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    if (hours >= 7 && now < hours < 19){} else {}
});
```

Comment: You mistyped "now.getHours()". Thank you however for the answer.